# how to enable ios keyboard return key functionalities in xcode?

Tags: ios, swift3, keyboard, xcode8

How to enable return key for first textField to  next textField and for the last text field do the same function as Login button does?

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code

```
 - (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textField {
    if (textField == textField1) {
        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == textField2) {
        [textField3 becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == textField3) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self callAPI]; //Call API Assuming it the last field
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Swift version

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == textField1 {
        textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == textField2 {
        textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == textField3 {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.callAPI()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use self.view.endEditing = true